# Load Kafka topic into Snowflake table using confluent sink connector

Tags: apache-kafka, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I need to load 5 Kafka topics into 5 different tables in snowflake. Kafka to Snowflake connection is established using Kafka Sink connector. The Kafka topic is an json format data and this is dumped into a SF table. Below are my questions:

1. How to create a Kafka Sink connector?
2. After loading the raw json format into Snowflake table, how to load the data into relational table (RDBMS column row format)?
3. How to capture the error log when loading from Kafka topic into Snowflake table?
   Need to capture in near real time data.

I am new to this Kafka+Snowflake. Can anyone please help me on this or share some pointers to refer.

Comment: Have you actually gone through our official [docs](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/kafka-connector.html) and they were not clear enough? I would like to hear if there is anything that we can improve in our documentation.

Comment: The doc u have mentioned - No, I haven't went through. Wil check that. I was referring to https://www.snowflake.com/blog/snowflake-sql-making-schema-on-read-a-reality-part-1-2/

Comment: That one is not specifically related to Kafka. I would say go through the docs I mentioned and if you still have issues after, post the questions.